# Invalid filter: 'markdown' django-markdown-deux

Tags: python, django, markdown

Before I explain my issue, let me tell you some basics of my system:
windows 10
python 3.6
django 1.9

I followed the documention of 'django-markdown-deux', from it, I learned it has four steps to be implemented.

Firstly: `pip3 install django-markdown-deux`

Secondly: add `markdown_deux` into your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Thirdly: add `{% load markdown_deux_tags %}` into your header.html

Finally: add `{{ post.body|markdown }}`, as I want to transfer `post.body` to markdown

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h3><a href="/blog/{{post.id}}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
<h6> on {{ post.date }}</h6>

<div class = "container">
    {{ post.body|markdown }}
</div>
<br><br>
{% endblock %}
```

after doing this, I have "Error during template rendering"

```
In template F:\django\mysite_1\blog\templates\blog\post.html, error at line 8

Invalid filter: 'markdown'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the tags in the template file which uses the tags (not in your `header.html`). In other words, you need to include `{% load markdown_deux_tags %}` in the same file as you call `{{ post.body|markdown }}`:

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}
{% load markdown_deux_tags %}
{% block content %}

<h3><a href="/blog/{{post.id}}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
<h6> on {{ post.date }}</h6>

<div class = "container">
    {{ post.body|markdown }}
</div>
<br><br>
{% endblock %}
```